# How to call postfix in vps from my local pc to send email to my yahoo account?

Tags: postfix, smtp

a ：my local pc， localhost.localdomain
b is my vps ，which build  postfix
c is my yahoo account.

To login b(my vps).

```
echo "test"|mail -s "test" account-in-yahoo@yahoo.com
```

The email can be sent to `account-in-yahoo@yahoo.com`

All configuration on my postfix.

```
postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = mail.domain.com
myorigin = $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Now i want to call the postfix on b(my vps) from a(my local pc) to send a email to yahoo account.
msmtp was installed on b(my local pc).

```
cat .msmtprc
account default
host domain.com
user root
from root@mydomain.com
password xxxxxx
auth login
tls off
logfile .msmtp.log
```

To send email

```
echo "test" | mail  -s "test" xxxx@yahoo.com
```

Here are logs on my local pc.

```
cat /var/log/mail.log
Oct 7 08:09:50 localhost postfix/pickup[23565]: D6FA3482226: uid=1000 from=<root>
Oct 7 08:09:50 localhost postfix/cleanup[25879]: D6FA3482226: message-id=<20171007120950.D6FA3482226@localhost.localdomain>
Oct 7 08:09:50 localhost postfix/qmgr[4739]: D6FA3482226: from=<root@localdomain.localdomain>, size=359, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 7 08:09:55 localhost postfix/smtp[25881]: D6FA3482226: to=<xxxx@yahoo.com>, relay=mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.216.26]:25, delay=4.3, delays=0.08/0/2.5/1.8, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok dirdel)
Oct 7 08:09:55 localhost postfix/cleanup[25879]: 38BC7482228: message-id=<20171007120955.38BC7482228@localhost.localdomain>
Oct 7 08:09:55 localhost postfix/bounce[26007]: D6FA3482226: sender delivery status notification: 38BC7482228
Oct 7 08:09:55 localhost postfix/qmgr[4739]: 38BC7482228: from=<>, size=1988, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 7 08:09:55 localhost postfix/qmgr[4739]: D6FA3482226: removed
Oct 7 08:09:55 localhost postfix/smtp[26008]: 38BC7482228: to=<root@localdomain.localdomain>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.03/0.01/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=localdomain.localdomain type=AAAA: Host not found)
Oct 7 08:09:55 localhost postfix/qmgr[4739]: 38BC7482228: removed
```

I can send email on b(my vps) to yahoo account,why can't send email from my local pc calling the postfix on b(my vps) to yahoo  account?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
a ：my local pc， localhost.localdomain
```

This is the exact problem. yahoo will not accept mail from **from=root@localdomain.localdomain** . in a nutshell you will not find it even in junk mail. they just drop your mail if the sending host is such.. I experienced this in the past.

Comment: How can i relay email from my local pc via  postfix in the vps to yahoo account?

Comment: localdomain.localdomain is not a legit domain. use correct domain

Answer (score 0):

```
dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found.
Name service error for name=localdomain.localdomain type=AAAA: Host not found)
```

Checking the existense of the domain in the *envelope sender* is a very common method used for fighting spam. It's not just Yahoo, but every reasonable mail configuration does this; only local delivery for such local host names could be permitted.

Using `@localhost.localdomain` may be caused by a misunderstanding that your local machine doesn't have any domain and, therefore, is not permitted to use any domain as a sender address. That's not true. Spoofing an email address you are permitted to use is not spoofing at all – email was designed in a way that every address is technically spoofed and only more advanced methods (SPF, DKIM, DMARC) can help to judge whether the use was legitimate.

If your VPS trust your local computer (either because it's a trusted IP or the connection is authenticated) and the VPS is listed in the SPF record of your domain, you can use the domain in both *envelope sender* and `From:` header address from your local machine.